# At what points does the curve intersect with the paraboloid?

Tags: calculus, vectors, parametric

$r(t) = ti+(2t-t^{2})k$ intersect the paraboloid $z = x^2 + y^2$

What am I missing here? Can I get some hints that lead me as to what I need to do here? I haven't the faintest idea where to start. I thought maybe write the vector equation as a parametric equation then solve for t and try to set the equations equal but that does not lead me to any points. As I still have two variable y and x.

Comment: $x=t$, $y=0$, $z=2t-t^2$.  Plug in and solve for $t$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

the points of the curve have coordinates:
$$
[x,y,z]=[t,0,2t-t^2]
$$

so, the common points with the paraboloid are such that:
$$
z=x^2+y^2 \quad \iff \quad2t-t^2=t^2
$$

find $t$ from this equation and you have the points.

Comment: Okay solving $2t-t^2= t^2$ gives me $2t=0$ and $t=0$. Where do I go from there?

Comment: x = 0 , y = 0 by plugging t back into the equation $x,y,z$ = $(t,0,2t-t^2)$

Comment: the book has (0,0,0) and and (1,0,1)

Comment: You found only one of the two solutions to $2t^2=2t$.

Comment: $2t-2t^2=0 \iff t(1-t)=0$ has two solutions....